# How can I fetch data from someone's Facebook profile in PHP

Tags: facebook

I'm absolute begginer in PHP but I'm thinking a way that can make earn something.
I would like to know if can I get data from someone's Facebook ?
For e.g I say someone go here : http://site.com/script.php  and inside the script.php there will be a code something like this :

```
$yes = include("http://facebook.com");
print $yes;
```

But I will modify some HTML to make the source output invisble, and then using some regular expresions I'll get the data I want and log them in a txt file. Or maybe using a iFrame , I don't know. But can I get the datas in this way ? Is this going to work ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the Graph API to do it in a easy way.
Check it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/selecting-results/